How to add "page/" prefix to standard WP static pages?
I'm trying to add a page/ prefix to standard WP static pages.
Example:
Convert this:
http://example.com/basket
http://example.com/contacts

Into this:
http://example.com/page/basket
http://example.com/page/contacts

What I have already done:
add_action( 'init', 'custom_page_rules' );
function custom_page_rules() {

  global $wp_rewrite;

  $page_id = $_GET['post'] ?? '';

  $wp_rewrite->page_structure = $wp_rewrite->root . 'page/' . $page_id;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse33551_rewrites_init' );
function wpse33551_rewrites_init() {

  add_rewrite_rule(
    '^page/([0-9]+)$',
    'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]',
    'top'
  );
}

This is triggered during page creation:

But it doesn't work anywhere else:

How can I modify the code to make it work?
Thanks!
